# Rehosting workflow designer in web

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, workflow-foundation, designer

I know WF designer has re-hosting capability.
Since it's WPF-based, I thought it might be rehostable in web, using silverlight.

Does anyone have any experiece regarding this?
Or, does anyone know an easy and powerful web-based workflow designer solution for WF?

Comment: In [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx) you can find an example based on WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working in the "WF area" too: the designer **can't** be rehosted in a web page. Keep in mind that WPF is quite different from Silverlight.

Not really answering you question, but... have a look at [SnapFlow](http://www.snapflow.com/).

If you find something useful don't forget to write a short note here. ;-)

Comment: SnapFlow look interesting. Just curious but is it using Windows Workflow Foundation and if so 3 or 4 or some other workflow engine?

Comment: @Maurice: I don't know all the details, but here (http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/NicFill/SnapFlow-CEO-Samad-Wahedi-demos-Silverlight-4-pilot-application-SnapFlow/) you can find some more information. They state the engine is WF (no version info).

Comment: This is not true. The designer can be run in a browser, just not with silverlight. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The WF designer can be hosted in the browser, just not with silverlight but as a wpfbrowser application. See details [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wfxbap/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4668)

This requires the .net framework on the client.. but it does work.

Comment: is the answer any different today? Additionally, when you say it "does work".. Can you edit a workflow that is on a server from a client machine?

Comment: Yes you can. But with the death of silverlight, a non wpf solution is further away than ever.

Answer (score 2):

When Microsoft introduce WF 4 at PDC2008, I specifically asked the question about rehosting in Silverlight and the answer was "No, it isn't something we are currently supporting but it seems there is some demand so we are conisdering it".

A little more than 2 years later and they aren't still supporting it so I guess it will be a while before we see that happening out of the box from MSFT